# Requiring data to be in certain format when read from PostgreSQL

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, psql

I had stored data from psql into csv files and had done some analysis.

I tried to read data directly from psql database and try to do analysis but the data is in different format like decimal.Decimal instead of numpy.float64

Due to this there are lot of errors that come up when I try to do the same analysis done using csv files.

I could convert the data read from psql to a dataframe having same data types.

I tried

```
df = DataFrame(cur.fetchall(),dtype=object)
```

but still the data is in `decimal.Decimal`.

Comment: Have you try to use `pd.to_numeric`?

Comment: There's really a `decimal.Decimal` type in pandas? Please post `print(df.dtypes)`.

Comment: You could also explicitly cast your decimal types to double in  your query: `SELECT decimal_column::DOUBLE PRECISION, other_column, ... FROM table`